# Site styling is missing after updating Porto theme to 2.4.6 version on Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2.4.6, porto-theme

I have upgraded Magento to 2.4.6 from 2.4.4.

Admin was working, But frontend was not workin due to old version of the Porto theme, It is not compatibility with Magento 2.4.6.

I upgraded the Porto theme to the version specifically for Magento 2.4.6.
The front end loads, but is missing some styling.

I checked the custom CSS in Magento Admin, and all the custom styling was there.

Any ideas on what or where to check?

Comment: Did you found a solution? i have the same problem